# I don't like [nice] tags!

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Apparently we have a [nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nice) tag! So lets evaluate it for burnination!

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Well, if we look at the description for this tag, it states,

> `nice` is a UNIX kernel call and the name of a utility employed to lower or raise a process' CPU priority.

I'm not a Subject Matter Expert here, but it seems to be a UNIX function or something. And people could obviously insert this tag as a joke, because that's how I found this tag.

Why should we even have a tag for ***every single*** UNIX command?

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Well, UNIX is ***technically*** on-topic, but maybe the UNIX StackExchange site would do better with this tag, since it is wholly based on UNIX.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, IMHO it does not. If I am using the input function for a program in python, I wouldn't add an [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) tag, would I? If I was trying to run a program, I wouldn't add a [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run) tag, would I?

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Well, not really. Sometimes new users create a function in their program called `nice` and then tag it with this, which has a different meaning from the UNIX command. I could also interpret it as, "My question is nice!". It has many different meanings.

So should we burninate it?

Comment: Just because it's on-topic on U&L doesn't mean it's off-topic here. And looking through the recent questions, most of them are specifically about `nice` rather than just using it incidentally, so the tag makes perfect sense there.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I never said U&L is off-topic. And if I ask a question about the `print` function in python, should I tag it as [tag:print]?

Comment: I don't see anything *wrong* with tagging it `print` if it's specifically important to the question at hand. I think the same logic applies here to `nice` too. The tag has a specific meaning in it's intended context, and I'm not aware of a large swath of off topic uses calling their questions "nice".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm no definitive source on this, but I'm gonna throw my hat into the "no" camp.

[The 4 tests of deciding burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11047824):

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

#### Unambiguity

The entire tag wiki reads:

> **nice** is a program found on Unix and Unix-like operating systems such as Linux.
>
> It directly maps to a kernel call of the same name. nice is used to invoke a utility or shell script with a particular priority, thus giving the process more or less CPU time than other processes. A niceness of −20 is the highest priority and 19 or 20 is the lowest priority. The default niceness for processes is inherited from its parent process, usually 0.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)
>
> For questions about the [Nice programming language](http://nice.sourceforge.net/index.html), use [nice-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nice-language).

The tag clearly applies to a very specific context and usage. It also specifically differentiates itself from another usage, directing users to a separate tag to maintain clarity and consistency.

#### On-Topic-ness

A question regarding a specific call in Unix most certainly does *not* fall outside the bounds of on-topic on SO. If presented in an otherwise well structured question regarding ["a specific programming problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or similar, it would definitely be on-topic here.

#### Meaningful Addition

If a question revolves around a specific call, whether about how it works, using it in a given context, or otherwise, then I can definitely see this tag having value attached to a question. If I happened to be an expert with this call, then searching for questions using this tag could very well be useful.

#### Meaning in Common Contexts

I was not familiar with this call prior to this post, so this is the one test that could be suspect. *However*, I'm also not aware of a lot of competing uses or contexts for "nice" in programming either, leading me to believe that there isn't a lot of confusion here.

#### Final Thoughts - Does it Cause Harm?

In the burnination FAQ post, the most significant criterion trumps and guides the previous:

> ...the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm

There are only [90 total questions using this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nice) as of this moment, and the majority of them (as far as I can personally tell) are about, or at least make use of, the call described by the tag wiki. There's certainly a swath of the usual low-quality posts with few details and few tags that fall through the cracks in here too, but I don't believe that's specific to or a fault of this tag.

All that said, I think this seems like a poor candidate for burnination, and not worth the resources required to do so.