# Have we been duped with the [duplicity] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag info for [duplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicity) states:

> Duplicity is a versatile backup program that encrypts backups using gpg and allows storage on various remote systems using a huge variety of backends such as SFTP, S3, WebDAV

None of the titles of the 61 questions tagged [duplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicity) are to do with programming.

The tag exists [over on Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/duplicity/info), where it is on-topic.

The [full set of burnination-request criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/232762) doesn't seem to apply, because it **fails** criterion 2: "**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**"

Should the 61 questions be migrated to Super User (where possible) and the tag burninated?

Comment: FYI, even mods can't migrate questions older than 60 days to other SE site though.

Comment: @AndrewT. In that case, what should be done with the questions?

Comment: Can't help other than closing and deleting (where possible) them...

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/duplicity/

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't see any questions about how to write the duplicity program, only how to use it: [Posts containing python and duplicity and is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+and+%5Bduplicity%5D+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: There are additional questions (not many) on [tag:duplicity-backup].

Comment: `FYI, even mods can't migrate questions older than 60 days to other SE site though. – Andrew T. 15 hours ago` And I thought my crystal ball knew this! Have I been conned too? O_O @AndrewT.

Comment: @francescalus We only get one tag per burninate request, so if this one gets done then I'll be able to raise that one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "should we burninate tag <x>" is always "yes"<sup>1</sup>. The problem is the effort involved, but that doesn't look like a problem here; [duplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicity) has 60 questions, [duplicity-backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicity-backup) 23, and some of those overlap.

I think getting a mod to migrate the questions that fall within the 60-day limit is the right thing, but the fate of the older ones are up in the air - particularly since quite a few have only these two tags applied. This may surprise some who know my preferences for content curation, but I think we should get those older questions closed and deleted - most of them are rather poor anyway.

I'm willing to spend a few days' worth of close-votes to help get them gone, but obviously we will need multiple people for that and they'd need to coordinate, since after the closures and deletions, these tags still need to be edited off the closed questions (if any) that remain.

(Sidenote: assuming the community agrees the older questions should be nuked, would it be appropriate to ask SOCVR to ask for help closing these questions?)

Then a mod can burninate both tags.

<sup>1: Apparently, "hyperbole" isn't something that is understood on Meta.</sup>

Comment: "should we burninate tag " is always "yes" <-- if that was the case, we'd never have a status-declined on burninations, but we do.

Comment: @Scratte `status-declined` in my experience is applied when the burnination effort is too high, not whether or not the tag belongs on SO. Which I fundamentally disagree with, but  without adequate tools, we can only move a few rocks, not mountains.

Comment: I've seen it used when there's disagreement with the burnination. Not everything should be removed.

Comment: *The answer to "should we burninate tag " is always "yes".* Not always. See the burnination request on [seeeduino].

Comment: _"should we burninate tag " is always "yes"_ --> Here is a status-declined on my burnination request.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401307/i-dont-like-nice-tags

Comment: *The answer to "should we burninate tag " is always "yes"* - so, no discretion, no thoughtful analysis, no reasoned and rational consideration - just "YES!" and blow it away? Hmmm........

Comment: @IanKemp Maybe if you wrote 'The answer to "should we burninate tag " is *almost* always "yes".' then people would be able to appreciate the rest of this answer.

Comment: Man, if you fail to tag your answers with [tag:hyperbole], don't blame the playas, blame the game.  "But Yakk", you say, "MSO doesn't support tags on answers".  I say, good job! You are blaming the game.  Keep it up!

Comment: Wow, people stopped reading after the first sentence... color me surprised.